# Database structure for user activity done right way?

Tags: sql, mysql, database-design, data-structures, relational-database

what is the right way to do user activity logs like how facebook does it and really fast at it too. i have a website for a client, which has activity logs the activity of user and show to his/her friends/family/followers but its very slow, we are willing to make changes in database, if it will help improve user interactivity and do the logs right way. im sure lots of people already research on it, but i cant find any links for it, that shows how its done proper way, so i can implement that too. any help?

**Desired Output of activities**

[image]

Comment: What is the current structure?  Knowing that would help people suggest ways to improve it.  What kind of machine hardware, how many users, current response time, desired response time, ect.  Otherwise the question ends up too vague.

Comment: well i want to know what would be the best table structure for this thing and really, easy way to say is facebook. everyone knows how activities work on facebook, just want to know what table structure should i use to set it up like them.

Comment: Lots of people re-invent the wheel these days.  Yes of course it has been done. If your "database" is low, then sure, it needs work.  Post your DDL.

Comment: You may want to check out these projects: Cassandra, Hadoop, Pig and HBase.  It's what twitter and Facebook(I think) use for database engines/filesystems/mapreduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Facebook's architecture is highly scalable, and they have a lot of "front doors" to data requests, and some real muscle behind that to crunch data effectively.

The first question is, how many concurrent users is this app supposed to handle? <100, just make sure your data layer is well-indexed and that you're making "smart" queries (get exactly the data you need to show a page, no more no less, using indexed criteria). If there's a lot of data to return for a query, chunkify it in the query (`SELECT TOP 25 ... FROM Activity WHERE Activity.Date < <date of the last record of the last page you retrieved>`) Low hundreds, think about a replication server to separate non-realtime or less often-used tasks, or simply to load-balance. High hundreds, start thinking of a server cluster with distributed tables and bulk transaction shipping. More than that and you're beyond my expertise on enterprise architecture.

Your first steps in any case:

- Profile your DB. See the queries produced by each action the user can take, and look critically at whether that query is the most efficient way to do the job. Refactor cursor-based operations; you DO NOT WANT these in any operation expected to execute quickly because they short-circuit a lot of the muscle the SQL engine can give you in crunching numbers.
- Identify criteria most often used to filter/retrieve results, especially with equality, and make those clustered primary keys. A clustered key will cause the server to arrange data with the same criteria on the same pages of data for faster retrieval of data likely to be retrieved in blocks. Be careful, though; too many indices will reduce performance.
- If the query looks good, and it's executed against a well-indexed schema, but it's still slow, consider refactoring the query into a table-valued function or stored procedure. Those are precompiled, and a query plan pre-engineered, saving you that overhead on a common DB call. They also require less information to be sent over the network.
- Cache the results of some of the more expensive queries, especially data shared by several pages and/or data unlikely to change quickly, in a session store or other in-memory repository on the webserver side. You'll need a lot of memory available in your webserver.
- Still not enough? Throw some more hardware muscle into the DB server computer.
- Consider a distributed model; most major DBMSes can work in a cluster environment. How you structure that model depends on your schema and the operations performed; most often, separating data by geographic region works well, even for a giant like Facebook.
- While you're doing all this, you can make the UI more responsive by incorporating asynchronous technologies like AJAX; the frame of your page can load and display in the browser while the DB server's still churning, then the data can follow asynchronously and be rendered into the page in a delayed fashion.

Comment: can you suggest any table structure for the activity table. so i can show it like facebook shows.

Comment: In general, avoid "wide" tables. A "narrow" (few fields per record), "deep" (lots of records) table is easier to pull from and benefits most from indexes. Facebook has a MASSIVE server cluster (900 master/slave failover pairs), but the conceptual schema is little more than a table for persistent user data (profiles), with a cross-reference table maintaining the friends network, and a very deep but narrow table for ALL posts on the site, which is heavily indexed and partitioned, and queried by looking for all posts either from that user, or written to that user (on their wall by a friend).

Comment: i have found this, what you think of this approach? http://groups.drupal.org/node/19249  this approach seems very dynamic and activities shows like facebook shows.